# I am writing a c# windows form code

Tags: c#

I am writing a c# windows form code to 
get the number from button1 and button2 and add them together in a text box but The compiler argues on the convert.toint32(textbox3.text) statement
and also it increases the value of the `two variable` and `three variable` how can I keep it constant but increase the value of textbox
and I need a solution?

```
  int Three = 0;
    int Two   = 0;
    //int one   = 0;
    int sum   = 0;
   // int sum   = 0;
    //int dec   = 0;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show("Enter the teams` name");

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Three += 3;
        //textBox3.Text = sum.ToString();
        Three += 3;
        sum = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + Three;
        textBox3.Text = sum.ToString();


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Two += 2;
        sum = Two + Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + Three;
        textBox3.Text =Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + Two.ToString();




    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox3.Text = 0.ToString();
     }
```

`

Comment: `The compiler argues ...` Do not lower yourself by arguing with it :)

Comment: Initially the textbox is empty. You cannot Convert.ToInt32 an empty string

Comment: Initialize `Three` to `3` not zero. And do not increase its value when the button is clicked. Right now you increase the value every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
sum = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + Three;
```

To

```
sum = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text == "" ? "0" : textBox3.Text) + 3;
```

Also, remove

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text = 0.ToString(); // this
}
```

because it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables belong to class and they are accessible for initialization in constructor. This can be done in many ways but you need to check if textboxes have values then try to convert it and add it.

```
private int Two;
private int Three;
private int sum;

public Form1()
{
    this.Two = 0;
    this.Three = 0;
    this.sum = 0;
    InitializeComponent();

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // MessageBox.Show("Enter the teams` name");

}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Three += 3;
    sum = textBox3.Text != String.Empty ? Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) : 0;
    textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(sum + this.Three);
}

... same for number Two

private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text = "0";
}
```